# makefile and git path problem on different computer

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

In my makefile i have a path variable

```
SDK_PATH = /home/myname/Documents/SimplicityStudio_v4
```

But this one is on my other computer another path that i have to adapt every time that i push on git and that i start working on my other computer.
I tried to add the makefile in the .gitignore but the problem is that it will be deleted every time.

I have tried to add a variable in my .bachrc without success

Could you please help me to find a solution

regards,

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What are you trying to accomplish? This feels like a half-question at the moment :) Are you asking how to manage software dependencies in a project?

Comment: You could set SDK_PATH on each machine in your .profile/.bashrc and then in your makefile check that it's set/or use a default if unset. Make sure you source your .profile/.bashrc or start a new instance of your shell otherwise it won't update anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a mapping in the makefile hostname to variable value, e.g.:

```
hostname := $(shell hostname)

# Path for hostname one.
SDK_PATH.one := /home/someone/Documents/SimplicityStudio_v4

# Use a hostname-specific value, if any, otherwise a default.
SDK_PATH := $(or ${SDK_PATH.${hostname}},/home/myname/Documents/SimplicityStudio_v4)

$(info SDK_PATH=${SDK_PATH})
```

Output:

```
$ make
SDK_PATH=/home/myname/Documents/SimplicityStudio_v4

# Now override hostname value.
$ make hostname=one
SDK_PATH=/home/someone/Documents/SimplicityStudio_v4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option to set variable in the makefile:

```
VAR ?= value
```

In that case the `VAR` will be set if it was not yet. In any case, you can set the environment variable before running the `make` utility:

```
VAR=value make all
```